# How to pass values as hidden loaded from ajax call dynamically after the form load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner in ASP.Net MVC and I am stuck at one place. So, I have on form with couple of fields and a drodpown. based on dropdown I need to make an ajax request to
get the entire datettime object.
Also, when I get the datetime I DO NOT want the user to see the fetched datetime. But I want to be able to access it when form submits. In a nutshell.

1. change dropdown - Done
2. on change make an ajax request - Done
3. get the datetime (DO NOT SHOW ON UI)
4. On form submit send all the form details along with the fetched datetime.

Below is my novice attempt

**Model:**

```
public class PaymentFormMV
{
     // some other fields
     public DateTime? Dte { get; set; }
}
```

**Widget Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetDate(int selectedUnitType)
{
    DateTime result = MoveInHelper.GetDateTime(selectedUnitType);
    // result is of type datetime
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**JS FIle:**

```
Ajax Call:
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Widget/GetDate',
        data: { selectedUnitType: selectedUnitType},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
        I am getting the data here SUCCESSFULLY
            ***WHAT TO DO HERE***
        },
        error: function () {
            DisplayError('Failed to load the payment tab.');
        }
    });
}
```

**CSHTML File:**

```
@PaymentFormMV
// What HTMLhelper to put here
```

On a side note: If I open a form and I already have some value let's say ID and I want to send that as hidden then I do something like below

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
```

and on formsubmit I am able to fetch the ID value.

But my case is `I get the value dynamically after the form is loaded`. So, I am confused **how to update may be a hidden DOM element which can take datetime object an receive it on form submit**. Please help me I am lost.

Comment: You would either serialize your form and send to controller via Ajax, or if you accept the post back, you would simply create a form and map the input to the controller action with all the parameters of each input name that it accepts.

Comment: What is the point of this - why not just get the `DateTime` value in the POST method when you submit the form?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Oh.. You mean I can directly fetch the datetime in the backend itself in the HTTPPOST controller action method as anyways I do not intend to show datetime to the user. That totally makes sense. I will try this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data to a hidden field, receive it on form submit,

First, init a hidden input

`@Html.Hidden("Dte")`

and your ajax function success, pass the date value to the hidden field

```
  success: function (data) {
     $("#Dte").val(data); 
    }
```

your form submit action, get the value, if your action expecting the model, it will automatically detect the value, if not, you can get it using FormCollection["input name here"],
this one will return you the value submitted of the input name passed

`var thehiddendate = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["Dte"])`

Comment: HTML HELPER version please.

Comment: It's not strongly tied to model right? Do I need to add "For" keyword for strongly typed hidden input element?